# Python Unable to update coordinates of JSON string

Tags: python, json, for-loop, pyodbc, reverse-geocoding

I fetch the JSON data from a sql table and parse it so that I get few components from it, but for a particular column I'm unable to do it. The `lat` and `lng` remains NULL, else every things gets updated.

Here is the snippet

```
ID=[]
    json_string=[]
    for row in cursor.fetchall():
     ID.append(row[0]) 
     json_string.append(row[1])
     #print('fetched')

    address_fields = {
        'intersection': [],        
        'political': [],        
        'country': []  
    }
    dumpData = json.dumps(json_string)
    json_all = json.loads(dumpData)

    id_index = 0
    for json_str in json_all:
        address_fields = {
            'intersection': [],        
            'political': [],        
            'country': [],
        }
        try:
            json_results = json.loads(json_str)

            print(id_index,' Updation starts')
            if isinstance(json_results,dict):
                first_address_components = json_results['results'][0]['address_components']
            else:
                first_address_components = json_results[0]['address_components']
            for item in first_address_components:
                for field_key in address_fields.keys():
                    if field_key in item['types']:
                        address_fields[field_key].append(item['long_name'])
                        address_fields[field_key].append(item['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'])
                        address_fields[field_key].append(item['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])
             # convert lists to single strings
            address_fields = {key: ', '.join(values) for key, values in address_fields.items()}
            sql = "UPDATE GEOCODE_TBL SET PXVAL=?,PYVAL=?, intersection=?, political=?, country=? WHERE GEOCODE_ID=?"
            params = (
                address_fields['intersection'],     
                address_fields['political'],     
                address_fields['country'])
    )
            print(id_index,'updation done')
            cursor.execute(sql, params)
            id_index = id_index + 1

        except Exception as e:
            print('Expection ' ,id_index)
            id_index = id_index + 1
            pass
```

Every column gets updated expected for **lat** and **lng**
Any suggestion where I'm going wrong here,

Thanks.

Here is sample JSON string

```
{  
   "results":[  
      {  
         "address_components":[  
            {  
               "long_name":"Nanabhai Moos Marg",
               "short_name":"Nanabhai Moos Marg",
               "types":[  
                  "route"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Navy Nagar",
               "short_name":"Navy Nagar",
               "types":[  
                  "political",
                  "sublocality",
                  "sublocality_level_2"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Colaba",
               "short_name":"Colaba",
               "types":[  
                  "political",
                  "sublocality",
                  "sublocality_level_1"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Mumbai",
               "short_name":"Mumbai",
               "types":[  
                  "locality",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Mumbai",
               "short_name":"Mumbai",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_2",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"Maharashtra",
               "short_name":"MH",
               "types":[  
                  "administrative_area_level_1",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"India",
               "short_name":"IN",
               "types":[  
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            },
            {  
               "long_name":"400005",
               "short_name":"400005",
               "types":[  
                  "postal_code"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"Nanabhai Moos Marg, Navy Nagar, Colaba, Mumbai, Maharashtra 400005, India",
         "geometry":{  
            "bounds":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":18.8947505,
                  "lng":72.80972229999999
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":18.894101,
                  "lng":72.8084149
               }
            },
            "location":{  
               "lat":18.8943079,
               "lng":72.8090094
            },
            "location_type":"GEOMETRIC_CENTER",
            "viewport":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":18.8957747302915,
                  "lng":72.8104175802915
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":18.8930767697085,
                  "lng":72.8077196197085
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"ChIJjdazXn_R5zsR__eePPSFcIs",
         "types":[  
            "route"
         ]
      },
      {  
         "address_components":[  
            {  
               "long_name":"India",
               "short_name":"IN",
               "types":[  
                  "country",
                  "political"
               ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address":"India",
         "geometry":{  
            "bounds":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":35.5087008,
                  "lng":97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":6.4626999,
                  "lng":68.1097
               }
            },
            "location":{  
               "lat":20.593684,
               "lng":78.96288
            },
            "location_type":"APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport":{  
               "northeast":{  
                  "lat":35.5087008,
                  "lng":97.39535869999999
               },
               "southwest":{  
                  "lat":6.4626999,
                  "lng":68.1097
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id":"ChIJkbeSa_BfYzARphNChaFPjNc",
         "types":[  
            "country",
            "political"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status":"OK"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake is that you are trying to access the parent key of the JSON from a child object.

In the line `item['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat']`, `item` is one of objects in the `results` list, but you are treating it to be the root JSON dictionary.

Using `json_results['results'][0]...` should solve the problem.

**Note: Often formatting the JSON correctly can reveal bugs in your code, always work with formatted documents when writing your parser, to make it easy.**

Comment: Nope I changed it to `address_fields[field_key].append(json_results['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'])` still there is no update

Comment: Have you looked at what the Exception message is when you catch it? If you are on Atom or VS Code you can debug, else `print e.message` to first understand where the problem is occurring.

Comment: I'm using spyder editor, It doesn't gives any exception message , it executes without any warning or error message

Comment: Yes, so that's why add the `print` line I mentioned above inside the `except Exception as e:` block. That's the point of having exceptions, they help you debug apart from other things. Also, the reason it does not raise any error and stop execution is because you have handled the problem with a `try... except`!

Comment: Added `except Exception as e:print (e.message)` but still no change

Comment: What is the output of `print(e.message)` when you run the code? Check the command window or console. Does this line `print(id_index,'updation done')` ever print?

Comment: No, after I execute It doesn't prints anything `runfile('D:/test_SOF_Parse_updateJSONdata.py', wdir='D:')

runfile('D:/test_SOF_Parse_updateJSONdata.py', wdir='D:')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157534/discussion-between-crazygamer-and-deepesh).